# Why is the reference passing in this code not working?

Tags: java

this is driving me crazy because it makes no sense.

In the following program, the `b` variable is not correctly set. `b` is supposed to be passed by copy, but because `b` is a reference to an object, this should work correctly, but it doesn't.

```
public class A {
private B b;

public void foo() {
    System.out.println("the value of b is : " + b);
    bar(b);
    System.out.println(b.getName());
}

private void bar(B b){
    if (b == null) b = new B();
    b.setName("me");
}

public class B {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}


public class MainTest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    A a = new A();
    a.foo();
}
}
```

After execution I get this error:

```
the value of b is : null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.A.foo(A.java:12)
at test.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a reference to a method, you are passing a copy of that reference. Therefore, if the reference is to a mutable object, the method can mutate that object. However, if you change the reference within the method, the caller won't see this change.

```
private void bar(B b){
    if (b == null) b = new B(); // this cannot change the reference passed by the caller
    b.setName("me"); // this can update an instance of B passed from the outside
}
```

For this method to work a expected, you should either make sure you never pass it a null reference, or you should return the newly created/modified instance :

```
private B bar(B b) {
    if (b == null) b = new B(); 
    b.setName ("me");
    return b;
}
```

and then assign the returned reference to the original variable :

```
b  = bar(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. NPE is expected here because of `if (b == null) b = new B();`. If you work on the orginal reference passed to `bar()`, its fine. The moment you do `new B()`, you are no longer working with the original reference.

**You cannot reassign the reference to a different object. If you do, then the changes made using the new object will not be reflected in the original one**.